# REGEX for only data and end tag

Tags: c#, html, regex, xhtml, tags

I am looking for REGEX which will give me data along with the end tag

e.g.

```
input:
-----------------
<p>ABC<p>
-----------------
Output would be
-----------------
ABC<p>

-----------------
```

it will only remove the first para

para tag,Not for the second para

tag and all text in between would be same.

I want to mention here that i am looking for

```
<p>ABC<p>
```

not for

```
<p>ABC</p>
```

Its for specific text file having irregular

tags

#### Example:

i have big xhtml file like...

```
<p>scet</p>
<p>sunny </p>
<p>             <!--this tag is to be removed -->
<p>              <!--this tag is to be removed -->
<p>mark</p>
<p>Thomas </p>
```

its a complete XHTML file.having body head etc tags
Only problem here is
extra tags
i am expecting output like this

```
<p>scet</p>
<p>sunny </p>
  
<p>mark</p>
<p>Thomas </p>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the input. Are there multiple lines? What about `<p>ABC<p>DEF<p>`

Comment: is the file you're checking entirely made up of paragraphs, or is it a complete xhtml document? (with head, body, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work, take html document in string xhtml

```
 public static class XHTMLCleanerUpperThingy
    {
        private const string p = "<p>";
        private const string closingp = "</p>";

    public static string CleanUpXHTML(string xhtml)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(xhtml);
        for (int idx = 0; idx < xhtml.Length; idx++)
        {
            int current;
            if ((current = xhtml.IndexOf(p, idx)) != -1)
            {
                int idxofnext = xhtml.IndexOf(p, current + p.Length);
                int idxofclose = xhtml.IndexOf(closingp, current);

                // if there is a next <p> tag
                if (idxofnext > 0)
                {
                    // if the next closing tag is farther than the next <p> tag
                    if (idxofnext < idxofclose)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < p.Length; j++)
                        {
                            builder[current + j] = ' ';
                        }
                    }
                }
                // if there is not a final closing tag
                else if (idxofclose < 0)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < p.Length; j++)
                    {
                        builder[current + j] = ' ';
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility: Use an xhtml parser that fixes malformed xhtml. One such library is libxml2. Then use the library to locate and remove empty p tags.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this excellent post](http://retkomma.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/nested-regular-expressions-explained/):

```
(?# line 01) <(?<open>.+?)> 
(?# line 02) (?> 
(?# line 03) <(?<open>.+?)> (?<DEPTH>) 
(?# line 04) | 
(?# line 05) </\k<open>> (?<-DEPTH>) 
(?# line 06) | 
(?# line 07) .? 
(?# line 08) )* 
(?# line 09) (?(DEPTH)(?!)) 
(?# line 10) </\k<open>>
```

This will extract only the correctly matching tags, but not the self-closed ones; it will also do a basic nesting check, but not much else:
input:

```
<p>scet</p>
<p>sunny </p>
incorrect
<p>
<p>
<pre>mark</pre>
<p>Thomas </s>
<a>asd</a>
<p/>
<p><a>this should match</a></p>
<p><a>should not match</p></a>
```

output:

```
<p>scet</p>
<p>sunny </p>
<a>asd</a>
<p><a>this should match</a></p>
```

Each line of output is one match. However, tags containing attributes will of course not be included. A regular expression that would handle more cases correctly would be truly horrifying to look at, even with the nice formatting showcased in the blog I linked to :)

In these cases (especially since I gather you need *valid* XHTML output) I would always recommend running the input through a specialized parser, preferably one which outputs the parsing errors nicely, and handling those errors, instead of hacking regular expressions. Don't know any good (X)HTML parsers though, didn't need to do something like that in a very long time.